# count top words for each author in mapreduce framework

Tags: mapreduce, word-count

I have a collection of files, each file contains the author's name and the words he used. Now I am trying to write a map-reduce code to count each author's top N words. The tricky part is the file may contains multiple authors.
so I how should my map-reduce framework be designed ?
pseudo code plus a little explanation is enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In one MR job count the words used by each author by creating a complex key of author+word and value count.

A second MR job would read those pairs (author+word,count) and map them to (author+count,word+count).  Write a comparator to order those keys first by author and then by count (largest to smallest) and a grouper to treat two keys with the same author as being in the same reduce group, regardless of their count.  You'll probably need a partitioner to make sure that all pairs for an author go to the same partition. The reducer will then be called once for each author and the values (word+count) will be provided by the iterable with largest count first.  In the reducer just write the author, word and count from the first N records from the Iterable.